# Revealing module pattern: func.apply(null, arr) vs. func.apply(this, arr) where func is within an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Would you please explain me the difference between using `func.apply(null, arr)` and `func.apply(this, arr)` in the code samples below?

```
var Foo = function() {
    function useMe(a, b, c)
    {
        document.body.innerHTML =
            '<p>a: ' + a + '<br>b: ' + b + '<br>c: ' + c + '</p>'
    }

    function go()
    {
        var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        useMe.apply(null, arr)
    }

    return {
        go: go,
        useMe: useMe
    }
}()

Foo.go()
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/YQsaJ/

```
var Foo = function() {
    function useMe(a, b, c)
    {
        document.body.innerHTML =
            '<p>a: ' + a + '<br>b: ' + b + '<br>c: ' + c + '</p>'
    }

    function go()
    {
        var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        useMe.apply(this, arr) // USING this INSTEAD OF null
    }

    return {
        go: go,
        useMe: useMe
    }
}()

Foo.go()
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3DvtA/

I understand that when `null` is used as the first argument of `apply` function, the global object, i.e. `window` is used as the `this` argument of `useMe`. For usage as simple as the above code, does it really matter what we pass as the first argument of `apply` function?

Comment: Is `useMe` using `this`? No. So does it matter in that code? No.

Comment: just like  user2736012 said, setting the execution context (this) is just usefull as long as you are using it in the function.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: `this` is **not** an [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3). The two things are completely unrelated.

Comment: no, not 'completely unrelated' : 'this' is a part of the execution context. Yet my statement was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions have a so-called context. This context is an object and lives in the `this` variable.

Example which alerts "Hello World":

```
function hello() {
  alert(this.greeting);
}

hello.apply({greeting: "Hello World"});
```

Your functions do not access `this`, therefore it does not matter in your context whether you specify *null* or *this*.

As of ES 5 strict mode, `window` is not anymore the standard context of a function, instead, it contains the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `apply` is the value to use as `this` within the function call. Since `useMe` doesn't use `this`, it doesn't matter what you provide. Providing `null` or `undefined` tells `apply` to use the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode).